# How to properly escape special characters using ngSanitize?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, special-characters, ngsanitize

I want to let user enter special characters such as "&" and then convert those to correct html when page is submitted. ex "&" => "&amp" I have read the examples and found **ng-bind-html** and **$sce**.

It seems ng-bind-html is useless for my need as it will only show html text sent from controller properly converted in the view. ex: it will show "&amp" as "&" to the user. So what I'm doing is converting the characters using "$sce" at the controller before sending it to server. Ex:

```
var accountName = $sce($scope.accountName);
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Or is there a straight forward way to bind the view to pass sanitized text to the controller, just like ng-bind-html but in a two-way binding? I'm using **Angular 1.2.4**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on references and examples found under **ngSanitize** module included in **angular-sanitize.js**, the ideal way to parse input into properly escaped html string, is by using **$sanitize** component. Ex:

```
var accountName = $sanitize( $scope.accountName );
```

For this, it is required to include **ngSanitize** in the angular app module:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',['ngSanitize']);
```

and included **$sanitize** in the controller where $sanitize is used:

```
myapp.controller('myctrl', [ "$scope", "$sanitize", function ( $scope, $sanitize) {
  // code goes here

  var accountName = $sanitize( $scope.accountName );

  // further processing after sanitizing html input goes here
  }
}]);
```

**$sce** is a service in angular that provides **Strict Contextual Escaping**, in which angular requires binding in certain contexts with values that are safe to be used. Further information can be found in [angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce).